# Good Idea/Bad Idea: Using Qt's QSet on very large dataset?

Tags: qt, memory-management, hash, dataset, compression

Is it a bad idea to use QSet to keep track of a very large set of fairly large strings? Each string is 54 characters (108 bytes). The set may contain thousands of entries (I'm not sure on the exact number yet). The QSet will only be used for insertion and membership query.

If it is a bad idea, I'm definitely open to suggestions. My 54 character strings are composed of only 6 different characters (e.g. "AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFF"). This seems like a good candidate for compression, perhaps? Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "Universe size"? Don't tell me that's the amount of strings you're planning to have

Comment: It's the the solution space. The total number of possible strings (many of which are duplicates). I will not be hashing all of them, nor do I want to. Perhaps I should've worded my question more carefully. I'll update the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realize that by using a built-in set, you're going to have some path-level compression based on the nature of your data. Of course, this depends on the container's implementation.

Look at some information on radix trees, digital search trees, red-black trees, etc. You'll see that you don't need to store each and every string, but rather the patterns. For instance, let's simplify your problem: we have only 3 characters that can appear an maximum of 2 times each, and each string is 6 characters long. Three possible strings are:

AABBCC, AABCBC, and AACBCB

With these examples, we could get away with using a maximum of 6 + 3 + 4 = 13 nodes instead of a full 18 nodes. not substantial, but I don't know what you're doing either. As with any type of compression, the more your prefix patterns are reused, the more compression you have.

Edit:
The numbers 13 and 18 come from the path-level compression. For instance, in straight C (for argument/discussion), if I am implementing my string storage class as a wrapper around an array I would probably just have an array of character pointers with each pointer referencing a spot in memory that contains a pattern. In the example I gave above, this would take 18 characters ( 6 * 3 = 18). Adding on the size of the array (let's say that sizeof(char*) is 4, our array would take 3 * 4 bytes of storage = 12 + 18 or 30 bytes total to store our patterns.

If I am instead storing the patterns in a sort of digital search tree, I make a small tradeoff. The nodes in my tree are going to be larger than 1 byte apiece (1 byte for the character in the node, 4 bytes for the "next" pointer in each node, 5 bytes apiece). The first pattern we store is AABBCC. This is 6 nodes in the tree. Next is AABCBC. We reuse the path AAB from the first tree and need only an additional 3 nodes for CBC. The last pattern is AACBCB. We reuse AA, and need 4 new nodes for CBCB. This is a total of 13 nodes * 5 bytes = 65 bytes of storage. However, if you have a lot of long, repeating patterns in the prefix of your data, then you'll see some prefix path-level compression.

If this isn't the case for you, I would look into Huffman or LZW compression. This will require you to build a dictionary of patterns that have integer numbers tied to them. When you compress, you build the dictionary and create integer id's for each pattern in your text. You then replace the patterns in your text with the integer id's. When uncompressing, you do the opposite. I don't have the time to describe these algorithms in more detail, so you'll need to look them up.

It's a tradeoff in simplicity/time. If your data will allow it, take the shorter method and just use the built-in container. If not, you will need something more tailored to your data.

Comment: I think this could be the answer I'm looking for. Could you please explain where the numbers 13 and 18 came from?

Comment: @dfetter88 Updated. Please see my remarks regarding prefix compression vs. general compression. Your data may or may not fit well for the container you choose. You'll need to find out what your container is implmeneted as (linked list? binary search tree?) and look at your data to determine if the container's overhead is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'd have any additional problems using QSet over another sort of container, such as std::set, a map, or a vector.  If you are wondering about running out of memory, that probably depends on how many thousands of the strings you need to store, and if there was a way to encode them more concisely.  (For example, if the characters always occur in the same order but vary in relative lengths, store the length for each character rather than all of the characters.)  However, even 50,000 of these strings is only around 5 MB, and 500,000 of them is only 50 MB to store, discounting storage overhead, which is a moderate amount of memory on modern machines.

Comment: Idea is good, but I'm afraid it won't work for my situation. In my strings, there will always be 54 characters, and there will always be 9 of each character. The order is the only thing that changes.

Answer (score 2):

QSet does sound like a good idea. It's basically just a hash-table and it can optimize its bucket size dynamically. Perfect.

Another suggestion for compressing the key:
Treat it as a base-6 number string (think A=0, B=1, ... F=5) and convert it into binary (int).

```
  QByteArray ba("112"); // instead of "BBC"
  int num = ba.toInt(0, 6 /*base*/); // num == 44
```

6^3 < 2^8, so we can represent every 3 chars in your string with a 1 byte int (or char) and make a bytearray of it. That would cut down the size of the key from 54 bytes to 18 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

From your earlier comment: "In my strings, there will always be 54 characters, and there will always be 9 of each character. The order is the only thing that changes."

Don't store raw strings then. You could just compress them into the 6 characters actually used, and then make a QSet of those. A trivial compression would be {a,b,c,d,e,f}, and if the character set is known beforehand (and only those 6 characters) you could even pack things into a 16-bit integer.

Comment: The character set is known before-hand. It is always the same 6 characters. There is always 9 of them. Order is the ONLY thing that changes. Even so, the string can be scrambled trillions of different ways. When you say "pack things into a 16-bit integer", I'm not sure how you imply to do so?

Comment: I think the breakdown is that ChrisV is expecting like-characters to always be next to each other, as if you can treat them as one character and expand it later to several.

Comment: Precisely. For example, if the character set is ABC and the string format is AABBCC (order of AA, BB, CC subject to change), you could store everything in 3 bits: 0=AABBCC, 1=AACCBB, 2=BBAACC, and so on.